# Sorted sub-list in a random list of numbers

Tags: sorting, random

Today I was asked by one of my friend the following problem:

If we have a list of *n* distinct real number (each 2 of them are unequal), ordered randomly, then at least how many of them we have are sorted ascendingly or descendingly? In other word, what is the minimum length of the sorted sub-list?

For example, if we have 3 numbers randomly ordered, we will have at least a sorted sub-list of 2. If we have 4 numbers randomly ordered, still we have at least a sorted sub-list of 2. But what about n?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.

If there is a random distinct sequence of (r+1)(s+1)+1 numbers (r,s are nonnegative integers), then there must exist an ascending sub-sequence of length r or a descending sub-sequence of length s.

This is the Erdos-Szekeres theorem.